# Adding an element from a tuple within a list to another list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples and I am trying to take a specific element from one of the tuples inside the list and adding it to another, separate list.

So, I have:

```
List=[("a", "\\"), ("o", "-"), ("e", "s")]
```

and I want to add the 'o' from the second tuple to another list.
I know you can specify which element of a list you want:

```
newList.append(List[1])
```

but that only specifies to the ("o", "-") tuple. How do I specify that I want to append just the 'o' from the second tuple?

By the end of the code I want to be able to write:

```
print(newList)
```

and it returns:

```
['o']
```

Comment: @Stanley R

Thanks for the edits. New to Stack overflow and still learning the format.
Preciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples can be accessed in much the same way as lists.  In your case you have a list of 3 tuples.  Their indexes are:

```
 0 -> ("a", "\\")
 1 -> ("o", "-")
 2 -> ("e", "s")
```

The elements inside each of these tuples are also indexed:

i.e. 
In the tuple ("o", "-") the indexes of the elements are:

```
 0 -> "o"
 1 -> "-"
```

Therefore when you append a list with the syntax to access "o":

```
a.append(List[1][0])
```

[1] refers is the index of the second tuple of the list (in this case ("o", "-"))

[0] refers to an index of the first element inside ("o", "-").

Best regards

Comment: Really appreciate the detail and explanation!

Answer (score 2):

`List[1]` gives you the second element of the list `List` which is the tuple `("o", "-")`.

You want the first element of that tuple which you can access with `List[1][0]`.

```
>>> List=[("a", "\\"), ("o", "-"), ("e", "s")]
>>> newList = []
>>> newList.append(List[1][0])
>>> print(newList)
['o']
```

Comment: No problem, up votes and accepting the answer are always appreciated :) (you can upvote multiple answers)

Answer (score 1):

You can index tuples just like lists with brackets.

Generally best not to name variables like types, so let's do this instead:

```
new_list = []
li=[("a", "\\"), ("o", "-"), ("e", "s")]
new_list.append(li[1][0])
print new_list
>> ["o"]
```